# Incorrect LST values for MODIS and Landsat in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series, land-surface-temperature

I am trying to plot a linear regression model using MODIS LST values and compare it with a Landsat 7 LST time series. However, I am not getting the correct values in the plot; the range of values being too high in reference to my study area. I have tried bit masking to improve the quality of pixels used in the calculation, but it had no effect on the outcome.

```js
  var terraD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01').select('LST_Day_1km','QC_Day')
  .filterBounds(geometry);

var roi = geometry.buffer(10000)

var filter = function(image){ 
  var qa = image.select('QC_Day');
  var bitMask2 = 1 << 4;
  var bitMask3 = 1 << 6;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(bitMask2).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(bitMask3).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).clip(roi);
};

var LST = terraD.map(filter)

var Vis = {
  min: -50,
  max: 50,

};
  


//declare global time variable
var timefield = 'system:time_start';

//convert to degree celcius
var celcius =  LST.map(function(image){
    return image.multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
})

Map.addLayer(celcius, Vis)

//Add NDVI band to all images and add variables for time series
var ND =  celcius.map(function(image){
    // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
  var date = ee.Date(image.get(timefield));
  var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year');// 'year'=unit of the difference taken
  return image
    // Add a time band(Independant variable)
    .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t').float())
    //add a constant band (Independant Variable)
    .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1).rename('constant'))
})

//Linear Trend//==================

//independant variable names
var independants = ee.List(['constant', 't'])

//dependant variable name 
var dependant = ee.String('LST_Day_1km')

//Compute the betas using linear regression reducer.
var trend = ND.select(independants.add(dependant))//Bands should be in order of independants followed by dependants.
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(independants.length(), 1)) 
    //reducer wants to know number of independant and dependant variables.

//The output of this will have two bands: 'residuals' and 
// a 2x1 band called coefficients (An image containing a 2x1 array in each pixel).
//To get a multiband image containing beta0 and beta1;
//O/p = [[a], [b]] to [a,b] using arrayProject and then
//{constant:a , t: b} using arrayFlatten()

var coefficients = trend.select('coefficients')
    .arrayProject([0])
    .arrayFlatten([independants]);//naming the output bands the same name as variables
    
var LinearFitted = ND.map(function(image){
  return image.addBands(
    image.select(independants)
      .multiply(coefficients)
      .reduce('sum')
      .rename('Linearfitted'))
})    

// Plot the fitted model and the original data at the ROI.
print(ui.Chart.image.series(
  LinearFitted.select(['Linearfitted','LST_Day_1km']), roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30)
    .setSeriesNames(['fitted', 'LST'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Linear Model: original and fitted values',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
}));

//LANDSAT TIME SERIES 
var sr = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
   .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01').select('ST_B6','QA_PIXEL')
  .filterBounds(geometry);

//Bitmask

var compositeFunctionSR = function(image){
  //Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadows and cloud respectively
  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(4).int()
  
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
  //Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
  
  
  return image
      .updateMask(mask)
      .clip(roi)
}


//convert to degree celcius
var celcius =  sr.map(function(image){
    return image.multiply(0.00341802)
    .subtract(124.15)  //273.15 minus 149 offset
    .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
})


//Add NDVI band to all images and add variables for time series
var ND =  celcius.map(function(image){
    // Compute time in fractional years since the epoch.
  var date = ee.Date(image.get(timefield));
  var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year');// 'year'=unit of the difference taken
  return image
    // Add a time band(Independant variable)
    .addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t').float())
    //add a constant band (Independant Variable)
    .addBands(ee.Image.constant(1).rename('constant'))
})

//Linear Trend//==================

//independant variable names
var independants = ee.List(['constant', 't'])

//dependant variable name 
var dependant = ee.String('ST_B6')

//Compute the betas using linear regression reducer.
var trend = ND.select(independants.add(dependant))//Bands should be in order of independants followed by dependants.
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearRegression(independants.length(), 1)) 
    //reducer wants to know number of independant and dependant variables.

var coefficients = trend.select('coefficients')
    .arrayProject([0])
    .arrayFlatten([independants]);//naming the output bands the same name as variables
    
var LinearFitted = ND.map(function(image){
  return image.addBands(
    image.select(independants)
      .multiply(coefficients)
      .reduce('sum')
      .rename('Linearfitted'))
})    

// Plot the fitted model and the original data at the ROI.
print(ui.Chart.image.series(
  LinearFitted.select(['Linearfitted','ST_B6']), roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30)
    .setSeriesNames(['fitted', 'LST'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Linear Model: original and fitted values',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
}));
```

I have tried masking bits 2-3, 0-1, to zero as well with little improvement. What could be the reason for these outliers and how can I correct them ?

Here's a link to the code if you want to try it out https://code.earthengine.google.com/76692d0db97a7aad5815d6a3aa53830d